# When I Import txt to VFP with Wizard decimals don't work ok

Tags: import, decimal, visual-foxpro

i have this txt file:

```
"1","My Product 1","Vegetables","15.20"

"2","My Product 2","soda","9.52"
```

but when i import that with the wizard on Visual FoxPro 6 my result in the table is:

```
1 | My Product 1 | Vegetables | 15

2 | My Product 2 | Vegetables | 9
```

I've used `SET DECIMALS TO 2` but it doesn't work. If I export again, the table in txt shows this:

```
"1","My Product 1","Vegetables","15"

"2","My Product 2","soda","9"
```

without decimals. So, how can I import decimals correctly to VFP with the wizard or with a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the format of your table, but here is something that will work for you.  I am creating a temporary cursor as opposed to a permanent table, but a permanent table could do the same thing.  You need to pre-define your columns in the same order and expected data type.  In this case, the price I set as numeric with a length 10 max, but 2 decimal positions.

```
CREATE CURSOR C_Import;
    ( someID  c(5),;
      someProduct c(30),;
      someOtherFld c(20),;
      somePrice n(10,2))
```

Now, if you append the text file as CSV (comma separated values), VFP will recognize the decimal positions during the numeric import.

```
APPEND FROM YourTextFile.txt TYPE csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If the the default decimal point is ',' you have to define before the append command: SET POINT TO '.'. Without that you'll get only integer value as price. 
Remember after append to change it back to the original value.